# android client -server communication server doesn't receive message

Tags: android, client

I am just started to learn android&java. Now i am trying to estabilish simple udp connection between android and pc. but it looks that my server doesn't receive messages from android; the one line it wrote in console listening to the port... and then nothing happens.
firstly i ran server code in neatbeans, than i ran my client in android emulator. Help wanted!

```
client:

    package com.asd.soed;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        Button button;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Thread thread=new Thread (new Client());
                    thread.start();
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }

package com.asd.soed;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import android.util.Log;

public class Client implements Runnable {
Client()
{
    run();
}
    @Override

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            String messageStr = "Hello Android!";
            int server_port = 9999;
            DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            int msg_length = messageStr.length();
            byte[] message = messageStr.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_length, local,
                    server_port);
            s.send(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    }


server:

    package serv;

    /**
     *

     */
    import java.net.*;  
    import java.util.Date;  

    class Serv  
    {  
        private static final int PORT = 9999;  

        public static void main(String args[])  
            throws Exception  
        {  
      System.out.println("UDP Server Listening on port# " + PORT);  

            byte[] buffer  = new byte[65536];  
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);  

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);  
            for (;;)  
            {  

                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);  

                System.out.println((new Date().toString()) + ": " +"Received " + receivePacket.getLength() +  
                    " bytes from " + receivePacket.getAddress() + ":" + receivePacket.getPort() + "...");  

                String value = new String(buffer, 0, receivePacket.getLength());  
                System.out.println(value);  

                receivePacket.setLength(buffer.length);  

                byte[] b = "Hello from UDP Server".getBytes();  

       DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, receivePacket.getAddress(), receivePacket.getPort());   
       serverSocket.send(sendPacket);  

       System.out.println((new Date().toString()) + ": " +"Sent Response of " + b.length + "b to " +receivePacket.getAddress() + ":" + receivePacket.getPort());  

             }  
        }  
    }
```